# How do I keep my REST API address in the browser address bar but call a different PHP page?

Tags: php, rest, silex

I have a PHP page that displays product details by passing in the product code like this:

mywebsite/product.php?id=1234

This has all the HTML to generate the page in question, with a small amount of PHP and some Javascript that makes an AJAX call to get the product details.

I have also written as REST API using Silex / PHP that the Javascript calls to get the product info from my database, which looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';    

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;


$app->get('/product/{productId}', function($productId) use($app) { 

    $result = getProductDetails($productId);    
    return json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}); 

$app->run();

?>
```

(function getProductDetails is in another PHP file that is included)

However, I want to convert the main page to a REST API that looks something like this:

mywebsite/product/1234

I've tried including the product.php page, but that doesn't really work at all. I've also tried redirecting like this:

```
$app->get('/product/{productid}', function($productid) use($app) { 

    Header('Location: /product.php?id='.$productid);
    die();
});
```

but then the product.php?id= appears in the address bar.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction, so that I can type:
mywebsite/product/1234
and that's what the browser show, but that I can use a page defined in a different PHP file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is what is called a "sub-request" in Symfony world (thus Silex also). You can check the [Silex's documentation for sub-request](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/sub_requests.html) but basically:

```
<?php
// if not using it, you must tell PHP to use this class
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$app->get('/product/{productid}', function($productid) use($app) { 
  $subRequest = Request::create('/product.php?id='.$productid);
  $response = $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST, false);        

  return $response;
});
```

Be aware that with Silex, [this approach has its limitations](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/sub_requests.html#lack-of-container-scopes) (mainly due to Pimple's lack of scope).

But I'm afraid that your `product.php` is a real PHP file so Silex won't be able to handle it by itself, in this case I would include the file directly:

```
$app->get('/product/{productid}', function($productid) use($app) { 
  $_GET['id'] = $productid;
  ob_start();
  require PATH_TO . '/product.php';
  $response = ob_get_clean();

  // now do whatever you want with the response
  return new Response($response);
});
```

If you want to return Json data check the `json` method on [Silex Application class](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.2/src/Silex/Application.php#L464).

PD: I also advise you to read the [HttpFoundation's documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#response) as you should never use `Location(...); die();` but a [`RedirectResponse`](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.html)

Comment: Thanks, using ob_start to record the output of the PHP works well, that's exactly what I was looking for :)